# Finding a multi value element in ElasticSearch Array

Tags: search, elasticsearch

We have an index of Users e.g.

```
{
   "name": "Eli",
   "cars": [
        { "model": "Honda", "color": "Red" },
        { "model": "Honda", "color": "Blue" },
        { "model": "Toyota", "color": "Red" }
   ]
}

{
   "name": "Don",
   "cars": [
        { "model": "Honda", "color": "Blue" },
        { "model": "Honda", "color": "Black" },
        { "model": "Toyota", "color": "Red" }
   ]
}
```

We are trying to retrieve all the users with a Red Honda, but we couldn't find a way to do it in ElasticSearch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since i dont know which elasticsearch version you are using, i'm referencing to the current.

What you are looking at is the following:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-objects.html
and
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-mapping.html
and
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-query.html

with the nested mapping you can create a query like the following:

```
{
 "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "cars",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "cars.model": "honda"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "cars.color": "red"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

link to example: https://www.found.no/play/gist/91c5a6c8c9fe81928b1cc497f8740a3f
(click run)

Be aware, this is only working when you are working with nested objects! The mapping must know this.